# How can I input a single right-to-left paragraph (Hebrew) into an English page/post?

Tags: text

I have an English blog. In one of the pages I want to include a Hebrew paragraph between two English paragraphs (I expect the English text to be left-aligned and the Hebrew text to be right-aligned). I can get the Hebrew text to be right aligned, but not in a right-to-left way (e.g. the period at the end of the sentence appears to it's right instead of its left).

I tried pasting formatted text from Microsoft Word, but it doesn't work (the pasted text changes from right-to-left as it was in Word to the screwed-up form I get on WordPress if I type it myself).

I do not want the admin interface to change, I do not want my entire blog to change to right-to-left. Only a paragraph.

How can I achieve that? 
The site is http://roee.co

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add a hebrew shortcode to wrap around your hebrew text and then use the CSS2 direction attribute to indicate the text direction.

e.g.:

In your themes functions.php:

```
function hebrew_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
   return '<p lang="he" DIR="RTL">' . $content . '</p>';
}
add_shortcode( 'hebrew', 'hebrew_shortcode' );
```

Your content:

> [hebrew]Hebrew styled right to left text![/hebrew]

edit: I've updated to use the dir html attribute ( spec docs said do nto sue css to indicate right to left ) and to use a p element instead

Comment: Please excuse my lack of experience, but could you please elaborate on where exactly I should paste these two snippets? Thanks!

Comment: The CSS goes in your css file ( style.css ) and the PHP goes in you functions.php file in your theme

Comment: I pasted both code snippets in the css file and the functions.php file (both were pasted at the end of the relevant file), but it doesn't work, the text [hebrew]בדיקה.[/hebrew] still has the "." to the right of the word instead of to it's left in the published page. The page I'm playing with is here: http://roee.co/%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%99-%D7%90%D7%93%D7%9C%D7%A8/ thanks

Comment: I do not see the <span> tags present as necessary in the frontend markup

Comment: Please check you've inserted the PHP in your functions.php correctly, I've also updated the code to be more syntactically correct

Comment: To be semantically correct, I'd recommend using the attribute/value pair 'lang="he"' to the P tag. In fact, you could omit the class attribute entirely and use the lang attribute for any CSS matching. So if you wanted to style the Hebrew text specially, you'd add a rule with the selector p[lang="he"] to your CSS.

Comment: Since the css I was using is gone anyway I put in the lang attribute in my answer as suggested